# Cannot `pod spec lint` pod because of `undeclared type: xxx`

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm in the process of 'converting' an Xcode framework into a Cocoapod. I've gotten pretty far into the process, but I cannot get the pod to lint. Its a bit of a hybrid project, using both ObjC and Swift, but it builds fine in Xcode, but not through lint, which makes me think something involving Cocoapods is screwy.

Error:

```
    - ERROR | [OSX] xcodebuild:  EonilFileSystemEvents/EonilFileSystemEvents/FileSystemEventMonitor.swift:17:43: error: use of undeclared type 'EonilFileSystemEventFlag'
    - ERROR | [OSX] xcodebuild:  EonilFileSystemEvents/EonilFileSystemEvents/FileSystemEventMonitor.swift:89:28: error: use of undeclared type 'EonilJustFSEventStreamWrapper'
    - ERROR | [OSX] xcodebuild:  EonilFileSystemEvents/EonilFileSystemEvents/FileSystemEventMonitor.swift:63:15: error: use of unresolved identifier 'EonilJustFSEventStreamWrapper'
    - ERROR | [OSX] xcodebuild:  EonilFileSystemEvents/EonilFileSystemEvents/FileSystemEventMonitor.swift:138:14: error: use of unresolved identifier 'NSStringFromFSEventStreamEventFlags'
```

EonilFileSystemEvents.podspec:

```
#
#  Be sure to run `pod spec lint rebekka.podspec' to ensure this is a
#  valid spec and to remove all comments including this before submitting the spec.
#
#  To learn more about Podspec attributes see http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html
#  To see working Podspecs in the CocoaPods repo see https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "EonilFileSystemEvents"
  s.version      = "0.0.4"
  s.summary      = "Dead-simple access to FSEvents framework for Swift."
  s.description  = "Provides dead-simple access to FSEvents framework for Swift by Hoon H."

  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/128keaton/FileSystemEvents"
  s.license      = "MIT License"
  s.author       = "Hoon H"
  s.frameworks = 'CoreServices', 'EonilFileSystemEvents'

  s.requires_arc  = true

  s.osx.deployment_target = "10.10"
  s.source        = { :git => "https://github.com/128keaton/FileSystemEvents", :tag => "0.0.4" }
  s.source_files  = "EonilFileSystemEvents/*.{h,m}"
  s.source_files  = 'EonilFileSystemEvents/*.swift'

end
```

Project:
https://github.com/128keaton/FileSystemEvents

Comment: I don't know what happens if you put twice `source_files = `. But you could simplify with `s.source_files  =  EonilFileSystemEvents/*.{swift,h,m}`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
s.source_files  = "EonilFileSystemEvents/*.{h,m}", 'EonilFileSystemEvents/*.swift'`
```

instead of:

```
s.source_files  = "EonilFileSystemEvents/*.{h,m}"
s.source_files  = 'EonilFileSystemEvents/*.swift'
```